# Is this an array?

Tags: scripting, ksh, array

I'm currently looking at an existing script that have something like this:

```
variable='val1 val2 val3 val4'
```

Is this another way of setting an array? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variable with a string assigned to it.

```
variable='val1 val2 val3 val4'
```

You can tell it's a string when we output it using `echo`:

```
$ echo $variable
val1 val2 val3 val4
```

#### Example of an array

To define that series of elements as an array you could do the following:

```
$ variable=(val1 val2 val3 val4)
```

When you echo out variables that are defined as arrays, you'll get just the first element returned, like so:

```
$ echo $variable
val1
```

To see specific elements in the array, you can provide an index:

```
$ echo ${variable[0]}
val1
$ echo ${variable[2]}
val3
```

Or all of them:

```
$ echo ${variable[@]}
val1 val2 val3 val4
```

Comment: @casey Ah, good catch, deleted.

Comment: @ChrisDown - sorry I thought you realized that and were just giving another position if it were Bash.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an array.  To create that as an array you would use

```
set -A variable val1 val2 val3 val4
```

which would assign val1 to variable[0], and so on.

What you have there appears to just be values joined by spaces () into a single string.